# Integrating redis with django

Tags: python, django, redis

I am newbie in Django. My task is design a backend where there will be login system (using the default user table provide by django). There are two other tables, one is the image table which has the imgvalue column which contains the key from redis database. The other table (imgacl), is to provide the access control to users for viewing the particular images which a required user has access. The redis database is actually storing the images with key-value pair, and that key is stored in the imgvalue column. Here are my codes:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    imgvalue = models.Charfield(max_length =250)

class Imageacl(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(Image,on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    userlist= models.Textfield(null=True)
```

The userlist contains the list of user which can see a particular image.
A separate python program for storing 50 images in Redis db. Suppose there are 5 users, the user1 can view 10 images, users2 can view 15 images...

```
import redis
from PIL import Image
rd =  redis.StrictRedis()
for x in range(1,51):
    img = open("{}.jpg".format(x),"rb").read()
    rd.set("key{}".format(x),img)
```

I have two questions:
1) How I wll integrate redis with django &
2) How I will provide the access control to users??

Answer (score 0):

You could use redis to store references to images, and store the actual images:

1. in the server, in case you allow your system to serve static files in a efficient way (have in mind serving files does also reduce your application performance if coexisting in the same server)
2. in a object storage service like S3, which can provide you good performance serving those images.

In redis, store the url strings for images:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
buck = s3.Bucket('name')
for object in buck.objects.all():
  # print(object)
  rd.set("key{}".format(x), object.key)
```

or if you stored the images in the filesystem:

```
import os

folder=os.listdir("path/to/img/")
for file in folder:
  rd.set("key{}".format(x), "path/to/img/%s"%file )
```

To implement user access control, have a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2080653/5476782) question, there are several django modules to get grained access control.